# Calling a public method of one component in another in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```
export class Foo extends React.Component {
  public render() {
    return <div>{this.props.children}</div>
  }

  public myFunc = () => {
    // does some operation
  }
}

export class Bar extends React.Component {
  public render() {
    return <div>Bar Component</div>
  }

  // Trying to call Foo's myFunc in here
}
```

If I have the above two React components, how can I go about calling `Foo`'s `myFunc` function in `Bar`? Please note that in this case `Foo` acts as the parent of `Bar`.

EDIT:

I did something like this in my Foo.tsx file

```
export const myFunc = () => {
  // does some operation
}

export class Foo extends React.Component {
  public render() {
    return <div>{this.props.children}</div>
  }

}
```

and then did `import { myFunc } from "./Foo" in`Bar`. This works but I'm wondering if it is the right way to do it.

Comment: You need some form of reference between the two components. How are they linked to each another, is one of them a child of the other? Or are they both childs of another parent?

Comment: Please check the last line. Foo is Bar's parent.

Comment: if foo is bar's parent you need to extend Foo. `export class Bar extends Foo`

Comment: Sorry, I've overread the last line. @Isaac, no, foo is not bar's superclass, but its parent in the DOM model, this does not have to do anything with the class model.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
export class Foo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>
              <Bar passedFunc={this.myFunc} />
           </div>
  }

  myFunc = () => {
    // does some operation
  }
}

export class Bar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div onClick={this.props.passedFunc}>Bar Component</div>
  }
}
```

Hopefully this makes it easier to conceptualize, but if you are hard set on passing the props via the `this.props.children` call, you can do this in the render function of Foo.

```
const { children } = this.props;

const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(children, child =>
  React.cloneElement(child, { myFunc: this.myFunc }));

return <div>{childrenWithProps}</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to pass it in via props.

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty if you want to call a method on the parent, this is the only way in React.

Comment: I edited the main post with a different solution. Please have a look.

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty it depends on what that function is doing. If the function changes some UI in Foo, then you should create the function in Foo and pass it as a prop to Bar. If it's a general utility function, that is agnostic of the UI, then it should be created in _neither_ Foo nor Bar, but in a separate utils file, which is imported to, and consumed by, the Foo and Bar components.

Comment: it's agnostic in the sense that the function doesn't depend on changes in Foo but it makes sense to put it there as it falls under the umbrella of what Foo is supposed to do.

Comment: Why not just put the function somewhere in the Foo file, and give the Foo file multiple exports then? e.g. export function myFunc & export class Foo. That way you can import the myFunc function into the Bar file. But it really does sound like a better use case for a utils file, since the function is being used as utility (not affecting the state of either component) in multiple locations.